# Are the degrees of freedom of a system decreased when the system is subjected to a non-holonomic constraint?

Tags: classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

Are the degrees of freedom of a system decreased when the system is subjected to a non-holonomic constraint? 
I know when a system is subjected to a holonomic constraint then its degrees of freedom decrease.

Comment: How do you define the "non holonomic" constraint?

Comment: Please answer this question